# How to create an Audio CD using C# or Java

Tags: c#, java, cd

I'm looking for an API that would allow me to create an audio CD from within a C# application. The CDs are to be created and closed in the same session (no rewrite required). Basically, my application locates files on behalf of a user, and, if a blank CD is present in the drive, creates an audio CD for the user. If no CD is present, it checks to see if there's a USB drive attached and copies the files there (this part I already know how to do).

I would prefer to write this application in either C# or Java, as I'm most comfortable with those, but I don't know how hard it would be to create CDs using either language.

There are several other questions here that deal with regular CDs, but I didn't see any discussing audio CDs.

Comment: Don't use Java for this.  You will need to interact with the operating system directly, which is not as well supported in Java as in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code sample someone wrote to make a CD Burner using C# and com interop to the Image Master API introduced in Windows Vista (with possible update to Windows XP machines to include the IMAPI).

[Creating Audio CDs using IMAPI2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/audio_cd.aspx)

Comment: I think that's basically what I was looking for. Now I just have one more piece of the puzzle - how to convert from MP3 to WAV (which is what that article was written for and assumes you have).